# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer' has been registered error in .Net core 3.1 console app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a Console app in .net core 3.1 with SignalR implementation. I am trying to self host the app but getting error :
EXCEPTION :No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer' has been registered.
I am trying to implement a signalr functionality. I have a MyHub class with all the hub methods implementation.
In Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread webThread = new Thread(webSocket);
    webThread.Start();
}
public static void webSocket()
{
    IWebHost host = null;
    try
    {
        var url = "http://localhost:5001";
        Console.WriteLine("In WebSocket");
              
        var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()                  
                .UseUrls(url)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

        hostBuilder.Run();
              
        Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Websocket exception");
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);              
    }           
}
```

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
        //services.AddControllers();
        //services.AddMvcCore();
        // return services.BuildServiceProvider();

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        //app.UseCors();         
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            //endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("signalr/myHub");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't use default builder static method:  `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be coded with reference to [the .net framework self-host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host) document, but you are using .net core.

If you want to use it in .net core, continue to refer to the following documents for the definition and use of hub.

[Use hubs in SignalR for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

### [image]

Please be aware of a problem, my code is copied from you. I think it is wrong about the access path of the hub.

Because your code is obtained from signalr self-host based on the .net framework, the path is wrong. Even if the current error is resolved, it may still be unavailable.

**Startup.cs file**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace core_selfhost
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR();
            //services.AddControllers();
            //services.AddMvcCore();
            // return services.BuildServiceProvider();

        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //app.UseCors();         
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                //endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/signalr/myHub");
            });
        }
    
        public class MyHub : Hub
        {
            public void Send(string name, string message)
            {

                Clients.All.SendAsync(name, message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

mohammadreza's is correct, if you are not very familiar with the configuration of WebHostBuilder, it is recommended to use CreateDefaultBuilder.

Follow your steps, and I have reproduced issue. You can check the below code, it useful to me.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     // CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
     Thread webThread = new Thread(webSocket);
     webThread.Start();
 }
 public static void webSocket()
 {
     IWebHost host = null;
     try
     {
         var url = "http://localhost:8080";
         Console.WriteLine("In WebSocket");

         var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder().UseUrls(url)
             .UseIISIntegration()
             .UseKestrel()
             .UseStartup<Startup>()
             .Build();

         hostBuilder.Run();

         Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
     catch (Exception exc)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("In Websocket exception");
         Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
     }
 }
```

**Test Result**

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your start up class?

Comment: @snehalgiramkar Sure, pls wait.

Comment: @snehalgiramkar I have carefully checked your code, and you can solve the current problem through my steps, but there may be a problem with the hub path.

Comment: Yes now the webhost is working fine. But the signalR Myhub is not working properly. Can you help with the Hub method implementation.  Right now I am getting error on Send method from MyHub class